# Properties of infimum and supremum of monotone bounded sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose $x = (x_1, x_2, ...)$ is a bounded increasing sequence and $x \in l^\infty$. Thus its limit is the least-upper bound of the sequence, i.e. $sup(x_i), i \in \Bbb N $.

Is it always true for such a sequence that $|sup(x_i)|\le sup(|x_i|) $?

Comment: Since $|\sup A|\le\sup|A|$ for any set $A$ (here $|A|=\{|x|\mid x\in A\}$), for your sequence it's also true.

Comment: So if I now say that my sequence x is bounded decreasing, would it be right to say that |inf(x)| $\le$ sup|x|?

Comment: It would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

**First** Suppose that $\sup a_i \geq 0$. 
Let $|a_i|$ be the sequence of absolute values. Then we must have
$$ a_i \leq |a_i|.$$ Hence
$$ 0\leq \sup a_i \leq \sup |a_i|$$ 
and if you take absolute value in both sides you have the result.

**Second** Suppose $\sup a_i \leq 0$. Then 
$$ \sup a_i \leq  |a_i|, \text{for every}~i $$ 
and so 
$$ \sup a_i \leq  \sup |a_i| $$
and by taking the absolute value in both sides you have the result.